# How are loaded SSH keys referenced by name?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, authentication, ssh-agent

I'm using [chef's knife ec2 tool](https://github.com/opscode/knife-ec2/blob/master/README.rdoc) which requires the **name** of a loaded SSH key (that was created in the Amazon EC2 control panel)

It seems strange to me that it uses a *name* to reference the keypair - because the name was created in the ec2 control panel:

[Picture.png http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/4236/pictureiy.png](http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/4236/pictureiy.png)

When I download the file I am just getting the `mykey.pem` file. Does that somehow contain the encoded keypair name? This key pair's *name* does not seem to be visible at the command line:

```
$ ssh-add -L
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQE69PeuHFtO[truncated]== /Users/me/mykey.pem

$ ssh-add -l
2048 b4:45:70:23:b1:f3:3b:01:11:23:45:67:89:0a:bc:de /Users/me/mykey.pem (RSA)
```

#### Questions

1. Is there a keypair "name" somewhere that I'm missing? How can I view these?
2. How does a third party software (like the knife tool) know which keypair to use based on the "name" of the keypair that appears invisible?

I hope those questions make sense - I'm happy to elaborate on any gray areas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Long story short, it uses [FOG](http://fog.io/0.8.1/).)*

If I understood your question properly, I guess it comes from EC2 like this:

[`lib/chef/knife/ec2_server_create.rb`](https://github.com/opscode/knife-ec2/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/ec2_server_create.rb) knows something about the SSH key name [in this section (`def run`)](https://github.com/opscode/knife-ec2/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/ec2_server_create.rb#L191):

```rb
server = connection.servers.create(create_server_def)
# ...
msg_pair("SSH Key", server.key_name)
```

this `connection.servers.create` can be found in `lib/chef/knife/ec2_base.rb`, [where we find](https://github.com/opscode/knife-ec2/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/ec2_base.rb#L57):

```rb
def connection
  @connection ||= begin
    connection = Fog::Compute.new(
      :provider => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id => Chef::Config[:knife][:aws_access_key_id],
      :aws_secret_access_key => Chef::Config[:knife][:aws_secret_access_key],
      :region => locate_config_value(:region)
    )
  end
end
```

i.e. it uses [FOG](http://fog.io/0.8.1/) which talks to AWS and thus knows *how to deal with* the key name....I suppose (?)

Comment: ahhh! ok, makes perfect sense! it doesn't know from the key - it talks to amazon, which tells it which key is associated with the name! very enlightening! thanks so much!!!!

Comment: You're welcome `:)`  (I wish I would have found a way to get code highlighting, though...)

Comment: says you can specify it on this page (http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) but i have not had luck with that either